# Visual Studio 2019 V16.9.0 no longer launches Destination URL after publish

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

Prior to V16.9.0, publish (WebDeploy) would launch the Destination URL after the deployment was complete, allow you to see that the site was running smoothly. A clipboard copy is now available, but is a manual effort subject to my sometimes forgetful mind. Is this a bug or a new feature? Certainly a change at minimum.

If it is not a bug, is there a quick way to edit MSBuild or the .csproj/.vbproj files to accomplish this objective?

[image]